# Example script provided by neo4j for JavaScript won't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am very new to the graph database ecosystem and for start I am experimenting with the neo4j. I would very much like to work with node and neo4j. So after a quick search I found [neo4j-driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/) that is an officially supported driver for JavaScript and an example provided which is:

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
const session = driver.session()
const personName = 'Alice'

try {
  const result = await session.run(
    'CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a',
    { name: personName }
  )

  const singleRecord = result.records[0]
  const node = singleRecord.get(0)

  console.log(node.properties.name)
} finally {
  await session.close()
}

// on application exit:
await driver.close()
```

now when I run this code, I immediately get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Now I thought I understood the error that I would have to wrap the try-catch block with anonymous async function to get rid of the error. The changed code body is:

```
const config = {
    "neo4j": {
        "url": "neo4j://localhost",
        "authUser": "neo4j",
        "authKey": "adminPassword"
    }
}

const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");

const driver = neo4j.driver(
    config.neo4j.url,
    neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4j.authUser, config.neo4j.authKey)
);

const session = driver.session();

(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await session.run('CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a', { name: 'Alice' });

        const singleRecord = result.records[0];
        const node = singleRecord.get(0);

        console.log(node.properties.name);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error Body: ", error);
    } finally {
        await session.close();
    }
})();

await driver.close();
```

But to my dismay, I have run into another error that is very cryptic:

```
{ Neo4jError: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=Sample database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1592397056399, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]

    at captureStacktrace (/Users/pc/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/result.js:263:15)
    at new Result (/Users/pc/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/result.js:68:19)
    at Session._run (/Users/pc/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/session.js:174:14)
    at Session.run (/Users/pc/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/session.js:135:19)
    at /Users/pc/neoNode.js:20:38
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pc/neoNode.js:31:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12) code: 'ServiceUnavailable', name: 'Neo4jError' }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had some problems with this.

First off, Natam Oliveira is correct. You need to use the `bolt` protocol, and await promises needs to be within an `async` function. For some reason the `neo4j` protocol is used in some examples in the docs. Additionally it would seem both examples currently provided by Neo4j—in the driver-manual and javascript-driver section—causes errors if you use them outside of some kind of unspecified environment.

There were some clues on the npmjs pagckage page, though, so by working them into the existing code, I was at least able to spit out some data. However I'm also wondering on how you could make this work inside the `async` function, so an explanation to how that could work with this driver would be very welcome.

Here's what worked for me:

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

const cnx = {
    user: 'neo4j',
    password: 'some passphrase',
    uri: 'bolt://localhost:7687'
}

const driver = neo4j.driver(cnx.uri, neo4j.auth.basic(cnx.user, cnx.password))

driver.verifyConnectivity()
    .then((cnxMsg) => {
        console.log(cnxMsg)
    })

const session = driver.session({ database: 'neo4j' })

session.run('MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 5')
    .subscribe({
        onKeys: keys => {
            console.log(keys)
        },
        onNext: record => {
            console.log(record.get('n').properties.title)
        },
        onCompleted: () => {
            session.close()
        },
        onError: error => {
            console.error(error) 
        }
    })
```

This spits out some movies using the *streaming API* as seen in the NPM documentation. (Note: It will only work if you started/installed the Movie database, so double check that you didn't delete it, as its deletion is also part of the Neo4j tutorial.) Now just change the `MATCH` Cypher query to whatever you like, and play around with the output, for instance by piping it to Express.

Sources:

- https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/client-applications/
- https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/#javascript-driver
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver
- https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problems you point to were really in my code. I did used the 'bolt' protocol afterwards. I only went with async/await syntax because I saw it in in the example script. I then opted for more familiar promise subscription syntax. It all worked out in the end. But all of these were not the only cause of the problem. Neo4j not able to performing any discovery made me think that I might was doing something wrong with the database. So i created a new one and provide the default password and user. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think your URL should be  `"url": "bolt://localhost:7687"`
And you still with `await driver.close()` outside an async function

If you are starting to use neo4j, look for an OGM (Object Graph Model) to help you.

Comment: How would you put it inside an async function so that it works?

Comment: async function run(){ await someFunction(); restOfCode.... }; run()

Comment: That obviously doesn't work in this instance. Can you please update your answer with a working solution?